# I have one Trimming Video Editor but after Xcode 11 I received this error No such module 'ABVideoRangeSlider'

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift4, ios13, xcode11

I have one video editor work well but after iOS 13 Xcode 11 I received this error No such module 'ABVideoRangeSlider' I don't know I will add new coco pods !! my framework it is red in Xcode how can I resolve It

```
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/ABVideoRangeSlider"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -iquote "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/ABVideoRangeSlider/ABVideoRangeSlider.framework/Headers"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "ABVideoRangeSlider"
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) "-D" "COCOAPODS"
PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the "Pods" folder from the project and running **pod install** again.

PS: Doesn't have enough reputation to add comments. hence this

Comment: Yeah but you can unlock the code and edit it to work in Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :- Open your terminal.

step 2:-  Update your cocaopod if not updated ( command :- sudo gem install cocoapods. )

step 3: - open project folder in terminal.

step 4:- command :- pod install.

step 5:-  Delete derived data from Xcode preferences and reopen the project.